# Rigged hand composed of multiple meshes

Tags: armature, weight-painting

Very new to Blender!

I have a hand and lower arm (made in Rhino) which is composed of multiple meshes (objects).
I applied bones as shown in the image below

[image: rigged hand]

But, when I use the automated weight it turns out like this:
[image: weighted]

After searching around I think it might be due to the multiple meshes and possible overlaps of meshes so that Blender cant automatically weight it.

My question is then:
Would it be easier to make a hand in one big mesh, or is there a workaround for this? The fingers has cracks and holes e.g. at the joints where they are connected by screws. I guess that's what is messing up the automated weighting?

EDIT: Uploaded the .blend file if anyone wants to have a go at it.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the .blend file? There might be weight groups in the mesh, you are just not seeing them because I don't see a bone selected or a weight group selected in mesh data tab. Also it looks like a single mesh and not multiple objects like you say.

Comment: They were individual meshes but I tried to parent them all to see if that resolved it. 
I will share the .blend file when I get to a computer again. 
Also, I forgot to mention that it gives the error message "blender failed to find solution for one or more bones". 
So there shouldn't be any weight texture, but then again. I have no idea. Picked up Blender today.

Comment: Yep if there was this error message then no groups were made. Will this mesh deform or is it gonna be only rigid pieces? Some manual work (weight painting or weight group assignment) will be needed to skin this nicely.

Comment: Jerrno: I've added the .blend now if you want to have a look at it. I'm not sure if I understand your question. I need to rig the hand, add a bunch of different animations and then import the hand + animations to Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to fix the armature bones to pivot in the center of the arm's ball joints:

   Select the mesh and in *Edit* mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) select vertices such that the 3d gizmo (the center of selection) is in center of the ball joint:

   [image]

   Snap the *3D Cursor* to the selection: <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> > *To Selected*

   Select the armature object and enter *Edit* mode, select corresponding joint and snap it to *3D Cursor* with <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> > *Selection to Cursor*

   [image]

   Do it for every joint. You can also set the [bones *Roll*](https://www.blender.org/manual/rigging/armatures/editing/properties.html#bone-roll) to align bones rotation axes - place the *3D Cursor* to the direction you want the bone to be aligned and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> > *Cursor*:

   [image]
2. Select the mesh, then shift-select the armature and parent it with *Empty bone weights*(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> > *With Empty Groups*). Now you should see a vertex group for every bone inside mesh data properties tab.

   Assign every mesh piece to it's corresponding vertex group. You can select a connected component with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>L</kbd>:

   [image]
3. You are ready to animate.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jerryno! That's exactly what I was looking for. I can now move the fingers around in Pose mode.
There's just one thing: The little finger had a lot of small fragments that I had to assign to "little.r.002". Which was not a problem, but - there are some tiny tiny fragments that I just cant hit and assign. So how can I remove them from the mesh? Image: http://imgur.com/cPQE1Kx

Comment: @Msjohansen Try selecting everything and *Remove Doubles* (left tool-shelf under Tools tab under *Mesh Tools*). This should fix any fragmentation of your parts.